# Enum cannot be pickled in Python 3.6 but can in 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, enums, python-3.6, pickle, python-3.7

Today, I ran into a problem in which an Enum could not be pickled in Python 3.6 but no errors occurred in Python 3.7. The following code demonstrates the issue:

```py
import enum
import pickle


class GoodEnum(enum.Enum):
    CAT = 'C'
    DOG = 'D'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


# Can be pickled just fine
print(pickle.dumps(GoodEnum.CAT))


class StringValue:
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


class ErrorEnum(StringValue, enum.Enum):
    CAT = 'C'
    DOG = 'D'


# Causes TypeError: <ErrorEnum.CAT: 'C'> cannot be pickled in Python 3.6
print(pickle.dumps(ErrorEnum.CAT))
```

In Python **3.6**:

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.6.9
$ python pickleerror.py
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nGoodEnum\nq\x00X\x01\x00\x00\x00Cq\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pickleerror.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(pickle.dumps(ErrorEnum.CAT))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/enum.py", line 46, in _break_on_call_reduce
    raise TypeError('%r cannot be pickled' % self)
TypeError: <ErrorEnum.CAT: 'C'> cannot be pickled
```

While in Python **3.7**:

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.7.5
$ python pickleerror.py
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nGoodEnum\nq\x00X\x01\x00\x00\x00Cq\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03.'
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nErrorEnum\nq\x00X\x01\x00\x00\x00Cq\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03.'
```

I could not find anything in the Python release notes regarding this specific issue. So basically there are two questions here:

- Why does this code cause this error in Python 3.6?
- Why does it not cause the same error in Python 3.7?

Comment: Got this error in Python 3.9, trying to make a deepcopy of an object, containing Enum. Is there a solution already?